# Configure Azure DNS

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to bind my azure website to a **third level domain**.

This is my configuration on the Azure portal:

[image]

This is my domain provied A-Record console:
[image]

And this is my domain provider CName-Record console:
[image]

With this configuration the application works on **http://www.test.mysite.biz** but it doens't work on **http://test.mysite.biz**

(on **http://test.mysite.biz** it is displayed a page "domain reserved")

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another cname to your website 
`awverify.test` pointing to `awverify.yourazureapp.azurewebsites.net`

check on https://www.whatsmydns.net/ to verify that `awverify.test.yourwebsite.biz` it is pointing to `awverify.yourazureapp.azurewebsites.net`